# scale text object size

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, keyframes

I've got a problem with scale my moving text, I have an intro moving but when I want to rescale it as when I preview what I have done it re-sets it self back or original size. Is there a way to save the size I want it to be.

First image: This is shown when I edit it
[image]

Second Image: This the size goes back to its original size after I preview it playing to see what will happen.
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is better the upload the blendfile, I don't understand what it is that you are asking. Do you want the text to scale in the animation? Or do you want to have the text to have the same size?

Comment: I want to resize the text, but everytime I seem to scale it. It resets itself back to its original size

Comment: So you want to keep it resized during all animation, right? Without more details, I think there is a keyframe before or after the one that sets X scale to 0.500. So you need to either remove all keyframes, or change whatever keyframes are set before or after the one that scales to 0.500. A capture from the Timeline/Dopesheet would help.

Comment: Yes I want to resize the text through the whole animation

Comment: the first image is the scale that you want?

Comment: Yes Glady, also does the Delta Transform work? as I used it make it smaller which made it stay smaller on the preview, but will it make it smaller when I render it?

Comment: i don't know what the delta transform does, but if you upload your file I can take a look and maybe find a solution (or someone else), you can upload it to some hosting service (e.g. pasteall or blendexchange) and put the link here.

Comment: Well by watching this video you will understand what I am trying to get at: https://vid.me/EcFe  and for the file on mediafire:

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/lrroy8n2cujy4rp/JuniorMotion+Intro+Template.blend

Answer (score 1):

First you must go to the dopesheet, then select the text you want to animate. In the dopesheet you see four keyframes, those keyframes you have to change. So go with the timeline (the green line in the dopesheet) to the first keyframe, the values of the scale is in yellow (that means it is keyframed) so change the x value to .5 and click on <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe (make sure you are in the 3D view, or above the value when you hit the <kbd>I</kbd>. Go with the timeline to the next keyframe, you are on the right frame if the values from the scale are yellow and repeat everything.[image]